# XSLT - Sort by a a custom string set

Tags: sorting, xslt

I have an xml as follows

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    <id>4</id>
    <updated>2012-11-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>ASSIGNED</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>3</id>
    <updated>2011-01-16T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>ASSIGNED</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>2</id>
    <updated>2014-12-01T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>EXPIRED</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <updated>2013-01-12T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>COMPLETED</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <updated>2012-01-09T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>ASSIGNED</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <updated>2011-04-18T16:55:54Z</updated>
    <title>COMPLETED</title>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

I want to sort by  with ASSIGNED first, then followed by EXPIRED, and then COMPLETED.
If there are more than one entries in each of these categories, I would like to sort by **updated** value descending.

I can sort by **updated** descending using xsl:sort, but how do I sort based on a set of strings {ASSIGNED, EXPIRED, COMPLETED} in an order

Appreciate your response!

Comment: Might want to tag with XSL. You'll have better luck with responses.

Comment: @Rick: [xsl] gets mapped automatically to [xslt].

Comment: @Jongware: at the time I commented it was only tagged with [sorting].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `translate` in the `xsl:sort` line to convert the first character of the strings "ASSIGNED", "EXPIRED", and "COMPLETED" into simple "1", "2", "3". Since the first characters of your strings are unique, that's all that it takes; it would be harder if there were two strings starting with an "A".

The following example forces a hardcoded `<feed>` (as the template match itself removes it) and uses an Identity Transform for all other elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/feed">
    <feed>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="entry">
        <xsl:sort select="translate (title, 'AaEeCc', '112233')" />
        <xsl:sort select="updated" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </feed>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Jongware, worked like a charm! Can you please tell me what if the titles share a common first letter? like ASSGN, ASSXP, ASSGP and I would like to sort by {ASSXP, ASSGN, ASSGP}

Comment: For a larger range of strings that cannot be trivially converted to a number, as here, I'd probably use `select="entry[.='ASSXP']` for each word in turn, and in the proper order. (From memory; the exact syntax may need some tinkering.)